# Get current date without time

Tags: java, date, time

I need to solve following issue. I need to create date for comparison with other, but the date has to be without time due to comparing timemillis.

I have tried many ways, but still unsuccessfully.

I would imagine format like this:

```
Date(2014-13-03 0:00:00).getTimeMillis();
```

Do anyone know how?

Comment: class `Date` is not suitable for those cases, use the class `LocalDate` in the Joda time library: http://www.joda.org/joda-time/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use a `Calendar` to solve this:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(yourDate);
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
Date desiredDate = cal.getTime();
```

Answer (score 1):

The best thing is joda-time if you can use it.

Otherwise, use Calendar API. call Calendar.set() to set hour, minute, second and millisecond to zero then you have a Date of the starting of the date.

But, won't [new DateTime().withTimeAtStartOfDay()](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#withTimeAtStartOfDay%28%29) be a much easier expression?

Answer (score 1):

In Java 8 you could do

```
LocalDate date = LocalDate.of(2014, Month.MARCH, 13);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Calendar.clear(field) method to clear the time portion of the date.

```
Calendar rightNow = Calendar.getInstance();
rightNow.clear(Calendar.HOUR);
rightNow.clear(Calendar.MINUTE);
rightNow.clear(Calendar.SECOND);
rightNow.clear(Calendar.MILLISECOND);
Date today = rightNow.getTime();
```

Answer (score -1):

```
long time = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-dd-MM").parse("2014-13-03 0:00:00").getTime();
```